# T-SQL - Select Using SubQuery

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL query where I have in my where clause a list into a `IN` condition.

Example of what I mean:

```
WHERE Id IN (11111,11112)
```

And what I try to do is the following: I have a linked server query where I have an `IN` clause.

And I have a subquery where I use a `JOIN` table to cross data but I need that in the `IN` condition use the same Id like the main query.

I hope you guys understand what I try to do:

Here's my code:

```
SELECT 
Name, 
Street, 
Number,
(SELECT loginUser FROM [LinkedServer].[Database].[dbo].[Users] T1 
INNER JOIN [LinkedServer].[Database].[dbo].[General] T2
ON T2.IdUser = T1.Id
WHERE T2.Id IN (11111,11112,11113,11114,11115)
)
FROM [LinkedServer].[Database].[dbo].[General]
WHERE Id IN (11111,11112,11113,11114,11115)
```

**i get this error:**

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

Comment: Yes - and what's the question? You seem to have your query all worked out ....

Comment: @marc_s: i have update my question. pls check it out

Comment: Can you provide your actual query. You seem to be referencing the exact same table 3 times, which is obfuscating your real problem.

Comment: @gvee: i have update my code. take a look pls

Answer (score 1):

To reuse same set of ids you could use Table Variable.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(ID INT);

INSERT INTO T
SELECT 11111 UNION ALL SELECT 11112 ....
```

then

```
SELECT * FROM    
(SELECT Varchar1, 
Varchar2, 
Varchar3, loginUser FROM [LinkedServer].[Database].[dbo].[Table] T1 
INNER JOIN [LinkedServer].[Database].[dbo].[Table] T2
ON T2.INT1 = T1.INT1
WHERE T2.Id IN (select id from @T)
) AS X WHERE
X.Id IN (select id from @T)
```

Comment: thanks for your advice, but still get the same error

Comment: @user2232273 I think I have guessed right this time check update.

Comment: I have solved it finally. thanks for your solution. i have write an answer and have mentioned you as an author for the solution. Many thanks. +1 for the key of the solution

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a join instead of a correlated-subquery:

```
SELECT General.Name
     , General.Street
     , General.Number
     , Users.loginUser
FROM   [LinkedServer].[Database].[dbo].[General]
 LEFT
  JOIN [LinkedServer].[Database].[dbo].[Users]
    ON Users.Id = General.IdUser
WHERE  General.Id IN (11111, 11112, 11113, 11114, 11115)
```

This will return the `loginUser` where possible.

Answer (score 0):

**i have solved it finally.**

The Problem was that the subquery haven´t a where condition to extract a specific Id. 
Without a WHERE Condition the query return more than 1 value.

**What i have done:**

> **Thanks for the advice and his solution Author: "LIUFA".**

With a combination of his code and some correction of my code i get the solution.

I have add one more column Id and give it an alias. In the subquery i have done the select from the Temp table
using a where condition. And its Working. Perfect.

Hope that this solution can help somebody to solved a related issue.

**Finally Code:**

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(ID INT);
INSERT INTO @T
Select ReferenceId From MyBigData


SELECT,
A.Id,
Name, 
Street, 
Number,
(SELECT loginUser FROM [LinkedServer].[Database].[dbo].[Users] T1 
INNER JOIN [LinkedServer].[Database].[dbo].[General] T2
ON T2.IdUser = T1.Id
WHERE T2.Id IN (SELECT Id FROM @T WHERE Id = A.Id)
)
FROM [LinkedServer].[Database].[dbo].[General]
WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id FROM @T)
```